# How to get a 'for' in clojure/lisp to just return the values without creating a list?

Tags: clojure, lisp

In Clojure, running this code:

```
(for [i (range 5)] i)
```

creates the list:

```
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

But what I'd like the for clause to do would be just to output each of the numbers without creating a list. What do I have to change to achieve this?

Comment: Where do you want to output the number to? A function in Clojure can only return one value, so if you want to return 5 values you have to put them in a container of some type - in this case it's a (lazy) seq.

Comment: I figured it out. The reason I wanted to extract the values in the for statement was that I already had an external list declared around the for statement. In order to accomplish what I was aiming to do, all I had to do was put an (into ... ) wrapper around a closed version of the external list.

Comment: Can you post an answer to your own question? This will help people who might have the same question as you in the future.

Comment: Good idea. I will do just that.

Comment: You also might edit the question to be more clear about where the "output" is supposed to go. I see another with a `println` call and it looks like the correct answer given how your question is phrased.

Comment: Clojure only returns one value from functions. That's why `for` returns a list and not multiple values. A list is one value.

Answer (score 3):

clojure.core has `doseq` for just this purpose:

```
user=> (doseq [i (range 5)] (println i))
0
1
2
3
4
nil
```

the nil at the end is the repl printing the return value of the doseq call after it finishes processing all the values

Answer (score 0):

Since I was trying to get the contents of the list inside of a separate list, what I did to achieve this was wrap the external list with an into clause like so:

```
(into
  '("original" "list" "contents" ...)
  (for [i (range 5)] i))
```

Making sure to close off the parentheses for the external list.